# Keeping Widget Applications Main Activity in BACKGROUND

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, launch

My widget is deployed in an applications which also launches a main activity.  Most of the time I want this main activity in the background but when I click on the widget it comes to the FOREGROUND and rather than the user seeing the widget change the application main activity displays. I can't get rid of the main activity because I also want to allow users to launch the application that contains the widget. Was wondering how this situation can be managed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` seems to keep the main activity from coming to the foreground. Not sure if there might be some downsides to this however.

Answer (score 0):

Background processes in Android should be implemented as [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Activities are intended to exist in the foreground and will suspend themselves when made inactive.

Comment: true, and I do have a service for all the background processes. But the widget is declared in the manifest of an application that has an Activity, A Service, and WidgetProvider.  The widget is one part of a large application that the user can also launch from applications list

Comment: Almost everything is in a service, but I thought the idea of a widget is something that interacts with an application showing the state of the application.  Most applications have activities.  Its not an either or situation, I want an app with activities and I want a widget on the home that interacts with it.  But I don't want anything I do in the widget to cause the Main activity in to display unless i specifically request it from the service

Comment: What I am saying is that I am not anywhere doing a startActivity on the main activity.

Comment: I am open to changing my widget provider architecture, but I need to interact with an application that has activities including a main activity in it.  Right now the widget provider is declared inside the manifest of an application that has a main activity.

Comment: I just don't want clicking on the widget to cause android to bring the activity to the foreground which is what it is doing now.

Answer (score 0):

> click on the widget it comes to the FOREGROUND and rather than the user seeing the widget change the application main activity displays.

You are the one who set up the `PendingIntent` to bring that activity to the foreground when something in the app widget is clicked. Fix your `PendingIntent`, and your problem will go away.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/PairOfDice) that uses `PendingIntents` to update an app widget without bringing any activities to the foreground -- in fact, the application has no activities.

Comment: Below is exactly how I have the Pending Intent and Main Activity fileter setup in the Manifest.

Comment: Widgets Pending Intent:

Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(context, TheWidgetProvider.class);
  buttonuttonIntent.setAction(ACTION_BUTTON_CLICKED);
  PendingIntent buttonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, buttonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


MainActivity.java intent filter:
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: No Activities is not an option for me since other parts of the application need an Activity.  The problem goes away when the Main Activity goes to the background and is partly solved by setting no history on the activity.

Comment: I also did a search of my entire workspace and nowhere am I doing a startActivity(intent) with an ACTION set to android.intent.action.MAIN

Comment: @Androider: `TheWidgetProvider` is an `AppWidgetProvider`, registered in the manifest?

Comment: yes its and AppWidgetProvider registered in the manifest it have a filter too

Comment: filter just on service broadcasted events

Comment: @Androider: I cannot explain the behavior. Here is a different (and more elaborate) sample app: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/34-AdvAppWidget/LunchList This one has a button on the app widget to randomly choose a restaurant; tapping the restaurant name opens up a detail activity for it. Even if I bring up the detail activity and press HOME, I can still press the button to change the app widget's random restaurant, and it does not force the activity back to the foreground.